# Using launchd to load and configure a kernel extension in OS X

Tags: macos, launchd, kernel-extension

I am writing a network kernel extension for socket filtering. To make it configurable, a userland program reads a config file and passes the information to the kext through a `PF_SYSTEM` socket.

If I want to have the socket filter up and running as soon as possible at system startup, how would I choreograph the launch?

My current idea is to use launchd to start a small userland initializer program. This program would use `kextload` to start the kext. After that, it would read the config file and talk to the kext through the `PF_SYSTEM` socket. Having done its job, it would then quickly exit.

Another option would be to have two `launchd` items, one for the kext (using `kextload`) and another for the userland configuration file reader. This would avoid the fork, but would otherwise be identical. Either way, `launchd` would have to run a quick non-daemon userland program.

However, `launchd` seems to be geared towards launching actual daemons, not for quick tasks that do their work and exit. The [developer library document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001762-104142) says:

> **Important:** If your daemon shuts down too quickly after being launched, launchd may think it has crashed. Daemons that continue this behavior may be suspended and not launched again when future requests arrive. To avoid this behavior, do not shut down for at least 10 seconds after launch.

This gives me the impression that `launchd` is not the correct way to do this. How should I organize the launch? Is my whole idea going in the wrong direction?

(As a side note, I want to give the user the possibility to alter the filtering options during runtime too. I imagine this can be done simply by opening a new PF_SYSTEM socket connection to the kext whenever changes are needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that caveat only applies to daemons that are launched on demand.

Comment: Thank you. If this is indeed the case, that is great news. Is this something you have found out by yourself, or is it documented somewhere?